# Using a Website-specific ConnectionString with a DLL

Tags: asp.net, dll, connection-string

**The Setup:**

I have a DLL that uses a ConnectionString to connect to a SQL database.  When I add the DLL to my website i have to add the connectionstring into my web.config in order for my DLL to function properly (this is by design).  Once I add it into the web.config then everything works fine (as expected).

**The Problem:**

The problem begins when I want to move the connectionstring into my Website's ASP.NET Application settings found in IIS > Default Website > Properties > ASP.NET tab > Edit Global Configuration... > Connection string manager

If I remove it from my web.config and put it there my DLL fails to work.  If I use the connectionstring anywhere else in my website (and not from a DLL) I can access the database just fine through this method but for some reason my DLL can only access it if it's in the web.config.

**The Question:**

How can I get my DLL to use the connectionstring that's listed in the ASP.NET Configuration Settings Connection String Manager instead of the web.config?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to look for the section from the general ASP.Net configuration settings, which can be retrieved through the WebConfigurationManager class, rather than looking for a connection string via ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings.

```
    // Get the connectionStrings section.
ConnectionStringsSection connectionStringsSection =
    WebConfigurationManager.GetSection("connectionStrings")
    as ConnectionStringsSection;

// Get the connectionStrings key,value pairs collection.
ConnectionStringSettingsCollection connectionStrings =
    connectionStringsSection.ConnectionStrings;

// Get the collection enumerator.
IEnumerator connectionStringsEnum =
    connectionStrings.GetEnumerator();
```

Comment: also, Linq to SQL overwrites the db connectionstrings every time you save the DBML so I always have to open in notepad to override it and then build it right afterwards.

Comment: Overwrites the db connection strings?  Meaning, your local config file?

Comment: No, I mean if changes are made to the designer.vb code for the DBML, visual studio will overwrite any manual changes when you save.

Comment: Yes, that's true.  That's a different issue from this.